# Jenkins java.version requires 1.8.0_241 but unable to

Tags: java, jenkins

Been trying to set my JDK install automatically but it does not have Java SE Development Kit 8u241
The highest Development Kit for Java 8 is as shown 8u221

Any possible way to install it? Require it to unit test
[image]

Comment: Take a look here: https://adoptopenjdk.net or here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html

Comment: @Oo.oO How to use those link for Jenkins?

Comment: You can simply install one of these and then, choose `Add JDK...`

Comment: @Oo.oO my linux had openjdk version "1.8.0_242" but my jenkins is running on1.8.0_121